# pangram function is not working in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#define number_of_letters 26
bool IsPangram(char* string);
int main(){
char check[100];
```

when i put the output as "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" the output is no a pangram 
and when i put a to z values on one single line is gives the correct output

```
scanf("%s",&check);

if(IsPangram(check)){
    printf("the string entered is pangram");
}
else{
    printf("not a pangram");
}

return 0;
}
```

there is the function for pangram

```
 bool IsPangram(char* string){
 bool flags[number_of_letters];
 int size=strlen(string);
 bool ispangram=true;
 int i;
 char c;
 // for all the alfabets to be setting them to false
  for(i=0;i<number_of_letters;i++){
    flags[i]=false;
  } 
 // for converting the uppper case letter to the small one
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    c=tolower(string[i]);
    if(islower(c)){
        flags[string[i]-'a']=true;
    }     
   }
 // for checking the the lettters to no pangram
   for(i=0;(i<number_of_letters && ispangram==true);i++){
    if(flags[i]==false){
        ispangram=false;
    }

 }
 return ispangram;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need use `&` when passing a string as a `char *`, since arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameters.

So:

```
scanf("%s",&check);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%s", check);
```

And some general advice: turn on compiler warnings to help catch simple mistakes such as this, and learn basic debugging techniques (stepping through code in your debugger, adding strategic `printf` statements, etc).

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` cannot get strings with spaces. So use `fgets`

```
fgets(check,sizeof(check),stdin);
```

Or use

`scanf("%[^\n]s",check);`

This reads a string till a newline character is encountered.
The default scanf stops reading when a `space` is encountered.

Comment: never use gets(). use fgets() instead

Comment: Also a good idea to specify field width when reading strings with `scanf()`, for the same reasons as avoiding `gets()`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` with the `%s` format specifier will stop at whitespace.  Try `fgets(check,100,stdin)` instead... that will read (up to) a full line, and limit the number of characters to 99 + nul so you won't exceed the size of `check`.  It may leave a newline as the last character, but your algorithm would ignore that anyway.

Additionally, in `IsPangram()`, `c` should be an `int` instead of a `char` (to match `tolower()` etc.), and change this:

```
 // for converting the uppper case letter to the small one
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    c=tolower(string[i]);
    if(islower(c)){
        flags[string[i]-'a']=true;
    }     
   }
```

...to this:

```
 // for converting the uppper case letter to the small one
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    c=tolower(string[i]);  /* <== c will always be lowercase */
    if(isalpha(c)){        /* <== Check that c is a letter */
        flags[c-'a']=true; /* <== use c, as string[i] may be uppercase */
    }     
   }
```

...for the reasons indicated in the added comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#include <ctype.h>
void uc(char*s){for(;*s;*s=toupper(*s),s++);}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
  {int i,j,n=0,c[256]={0};
   char*s,*w[1024]={NULL};
   do w[n]=malloc(1024),fgets(w[n],1024,stdin),w[n][strlen(w[n])-1]='\0',uc(w[n]),n++;
   while(n<1024&&strlen(w[n-1]));
   for(--n,i=0;i<n;++i)
     for(j=0;j<strlen(w[i]);++j)
       c[w[i][j]]=1;
   for(j=0,i='A';i<='Z';++i)j+=c[i];
   printf("It's %sa pangram\n",j==26?"":"not ");
   for(i=0;i<=n;free(w[i++]));}
```